# how to resume maven release which is failed due to tag already exist

Tags: maven-release-plugin

When trying to perform maven release , maven release build failed due to tag version is already exist.  Again tried to do release after removing existing tag  and  it is failing with the below error message.

[INFO] You don't have a SNAPSHOT project in the reactor projects list.

Answer (score 0):

- Note - I'm assuming that GIT is your SCM.

I'm sure this answer is coming too late - but for what it's worth the issue is most likely that maven-release-plugin has already updated and pushed (assuming you are using GIT) changes in your POM where it strips off the "-SNAPSHOT".  After that, the release process has failed due to the already existing tag, but the pushed changes remain.

1. Delete the tag/make sure the tag has been deleted
2. Revert the commit that was performed by maven-release-plugin where it stripped off the "-SNAPSHOT"

After these steps - re-try your release build.